# iOS 8 CloudKit: CKNotifications keep showing up, marked as CKNotificationTypeReadNotification

Tags: cloudkit

Whenever I query for past `CKNotifications` using `CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation`, I keep on getting a whole bunch that are marked as `CKNotificationTypeReadNotification`. And indeed, I have read them before, marked them as read (using `CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation`), and am updating my `lastServerChangeToken` when querying.

Why do they keep showing up?

Thanks.

Comment: Was this a temporary glitch that's fixed now?

Comment: @RogeSoft It does work now…and why it does—and didn't before—I'm not certain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This started working…and, unfortunately, I'm not sure why.