# What is the difference between CKNotification and CKQueryNotification in CloudKit?

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

Sometimes when I perform changes (for example add 40 records) on the first device, I get then 40 `CKQueryNotifications` on second device.

Although I can mark `CKQueryNotifications` as read, I cannot mark as read `CKNotifications`. Why? They always getting back to my device, after every launching. Why?

**How Do I fetch pending notifications?**

```
var serverChangeToken: CKServerChangeToken? {
    return UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)?.object(forKey: "a") as? CKServerChangeToken
}

func fetchPendingNotifications(notifications: [CKNotification] = [], completion: ErrorHandler? = nil) {

    var queryNotifications = notifications

    let operation = CKFetchNotificationChangesOperation(previousServerChangeToken: serverChangeToken)
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue()

    operation.notificationChangedBlock = { notification in

        print("+++++ \(notification)")
        queryNotifications.append(notification)
    }

    operation.fetchNotificationChangesCompletionBlock = { token, error in

        if let token = token {

            UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)?.set(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: token), forKey: "a")
            UserDefaults(suiteName: SharedGroupName)?.synchronize()
        }

        if error == nil && operation.moreComing {
            self.fetchPendingNotifications(notifications: queryNotifications, completion: completion)
        } else {
            self.perform(queryNotifications: queryNotifications, completion: completion)
        }
    }

    operationQueue.addOperation(operation)
}
```

**How do I mark notifications as read?**

```
func perform(queryNotifications: [CKNotification], completion: ErrorHandler? = nil) {

    var currentQueryNotifications = queryNotifications

    if let queryNotification = currentQueryNotifications.first {

        currentQueryNotifications.removeFirst()

        let operation = CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation(notificationIDsToMarkRead: [queryNotification.notificationID!])
        operation.markNotificationsReadCompletionBlock = { _, _ in

            print("marked as read")
            self.perform(queryNotifications: currentQueryNotifications, completion: completion)
        }

        OperationQueue().addOperation(operation)

    } else {

        completion?(nil)
    }
}
```

What is the output on console?

```
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
+++++ , containerIdentifier=iCloud.pl.blueworld.fieldservice, badge=0>
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
marked as read
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you mark the notifications as read?

Comment: @DaveWeston I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding why the read notifications keep appearing, the documentation directly contradicts the WWDC videos. [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckfetchnotificationchangesoperation/1515141-initwithpreviousserverchangetoke?language=objc) clearly say (emphasis added):

> If you mark one or more notifications as read using a
>   CKMarkNotificationsReadOperation object, **those notifications are not
>   returned**, even if you specify nil for previousServerChangeToken.

However, the WWDC 2014 video 231 (Advanced Cloudkit), clearly says that read notifications are **not** removed and are **always** returned so the user's other devices can still see them. The presenter even gives an example citing an app that highlights large transactions on all devices, and once any device marks the notification as read, any other devices should see that "read" notification and disable the highlight also. To do that, they must be able to peruse the notifications marked as "read."

So, we have to consider two separate attributes of notifications:

- the read/unread status: tells us if any of the user's devices have seen this notification.
- the server change token: tells us which notifications we've looked at on each specific device.

Save the change token you receive in the fetch's completion block, and pass it to subsequent fetches. That's the only way to ensure the device only sees notifications that are "new" to it. Use the read/unread status to understand whether the user has already acted on the event on another device.

Comment: So to clarify: they are 'read' notifications. And they stop appearing only when every device will see that notification?

Comment: And how do I use read/unread status? There is type: readNotification. You mean type or status?

Comment: They never go away, no matter how many devices see it. Think of it like an IMAP mailbox: when the message is opened, every mail reader connected to that mailbox will show the message as read. But the message (or in this case, notification) is still there, always visible on every mail reader. Depending on your scenario, you may or may not care about the read/unread status. To stop seeing notifications you've already handled on a particular device, cache the change token and tell subsequent fetches to start from that point onwards.

Comment: "cache the change token and tell subsequent fetches to statt from that point onwards". Look at my code. I did like you say, didnt I? What should I change IN CODE?

Comment: I don't know. You certainly capture the change token, but you don't show where you persist it. Do you write it to the user defaults? or maybe your own local file? Can you show the code where you write the token to persistent storage, and where you load it back again when the app restarts?

Comment: My answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42738885/1641444 shows how I save the change token to the user defaults and read it back again when the app restarts.

Comment: All I do is to assign to the variable after first fetch. Change token for the first fetch is nil. I tried to save the token to UserDefaults but I do not know how...

Comment: Well, that explains it. You're not permanently saving the change token, so it's lost when the app exits, so it's nil when you restart, so the first fetch after the restart is returning all notifications since the beginning.

Comment: Ok, I will change it and let you know if it works:) previously I forgot save to NSData first... I directly saved `CKServerChangeToken` and it didnt work.